# How to get Minimize button to appear on AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have been working with AVPlayers and AVPLayerViewControllers and I would like to know how to get the "double arrow minimize screen button" to appear on the video player.

[image]

I figure there are some settings, properties, or requirements I need to make this happen.

Does anybody know?